# Python script to reset email password

Tags: python, smtplib, imaplib

The email server we are using forces us to change password every 3 months. But I want to write a script so that I can run a cronjob to change password every 3 months, because we have around 10 mailboxes and changing password manually every 3 months is kind of tedious. 
Does anybody know if IMAP/SMTP python library allows to reset password or if anybody can point me in direction of some other library or solution which would allow me to change email password.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that MAP/SMTP protocol support changing password

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150988/imap-change-email-password-through-php